# Need help/instructions to build ffmpeg with libdav1d under Windows

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, build, mingw, msys

I am asking for help because I cannot build ffmpeg with the AV1 decoding library "libdav1d".

I am under Windows 10.

I can build ffmpeg without "libdav1d". To do so, I use msys 1.0.

In msys 1.0, I type:

```
./configure --target-os=win64 --arch=x86_64 --toolchain=msvc --enable-shared
make
```

and it works fine: I can buid ffmpeg in x64 mode. With a slightly different ./configure line, I can also build it in win32 mode.

But then I try to include libdav1d like this:

```
./configure --target-os=win64 --arch=x86_64 --toolchain=msvc --enable-shared --enable-libdav1d
```

and it fails, with this error message:

```
ERROR: dav1d >= 0.5.0 not found using pkg-config
```

So I tried 2 different approach:

1. I downloaded the source code of libdav1d from https://code.videolan.org/videolan/dav1d and I tried to compile it
2. I also downloaded the already built libraries (for win 64 and win 32) from https://code.videolan.org/videolan/dav1d

*** Concerning the 1st approach (build libdav1d from its source code), I have seen that I need to install meson, ninja and nasm.

I have seen somewhere that I should use msys 2.0 to do that, so I install msys 2.0 and run it.

Then I follow the instructions indicated on https://code.videolan.org/videolan/dav1d

But when I run ninja, I get compilation errors like this :

```
$ ninja
[1/161] Compiling C object src/libdav1d_bitdepth_8.a.p/cdef_tmpl.c.obj
FAILED: src/libdav1d_bitdepth_8.a.p/cdef_tmpl.c.obj
"cl" "-Isrc\libdav1d_bitdepth_8.a.p" "-Isrc" "-I..\src" "-I." "-I.." "-Iinclude\dav1d" "-I..\include\dav1d" "-Iinclude" "-I..\include" "-I..\include\compat\msvc" "-DNDEBUG" "/MD" "/nologo" "/showIncludes" "/W3" "/O2" "-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L" "-wd4028" "-wd4090" "-wd4996" "-DBITDEPTH=8" "/Fdsrc\libdav1d_bitdepth_8.a.p\cdef_tmpl.c.pdb" /Fosrc/libdav1d_bitdepth_8.a.p/cdef_tmpl.c.obj "/c" ../src/cdef_tmpl.c
..\include\common/attributes.h(133) : error C2054: '(' attendu après 'inline'
..\include\common/attributes.h(133) : error C2085: 'ctz' : ne figure pas dans la liste de paramètres formels
..\include\common/attributes.h(133) : error C2143: erreur de syntaxe : absence de ';' avant '{'
..\include\common/attributes.h(139) : error C2054: '(' attendu après 'inline'
..\include\common/attributes.h(139) : error C2085: 'clz' : ne figure pas dans la liste de paramètres formels
..\include\common/attributes.h(139) : error C2143: erreur de syntaxe : absence de ';' avant '{'
..\include\common/attributes.h(152) : error C2054: '(' attendu après 'inline'
<and many others...>
```

And when I try to reconfigure meson, I get this error:

```
$ meson --reconfigure
The Meson build system
Version: 0.59.2
Source dir: /c/projects/ffmpeg44/dav1d
Build dir: /c/projects/ffmpeg44/dav1d/build
Build type: native build
Project name: dav1d
Project version: 0.9.2
C compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 16.00.40219.01 "Compilateur d'optimisation Microsoft (R) 32�bits C/C++ version�16.00.40219.01 pour 80x86")
C linker for the host machine: link link 10.00.40219.01

../meson.build:25:0: ERROR: Unknown linker(s): [['lib'], ['llvm-lib']]
The following exception(s) were encountered:
Running "lib /?" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lib'"
Running "llvm-lib /?" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'llvm-lib'"

A full log can be found at /c/projects/ffmpeg44/dav1d/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
```

I have also tried to copy cl.exe and link.exe from Visual Studio 2010 in the msys 2.0 bin\ folder (replacing the already present link.exe) but I had no success doing that.

*** Concerning the 2nd approach,  (build libdav1d from its source code), I have seen that I need to install meson, ninja and nasm.

I download the zip containing the already built libraries of libdav1d from https://code.videolan.org/videolan/dav1d

Then I created a folder ffmpeg/libdav1d and I copied the bin, include\ and lib\ folders from the zip in this ffmpeg/libdav1d folder.

Then in msys 1.0, I run `./configure --target-os=win64 --arch=x86_64 --toolchain=msvc --enable-shared --enable-libdav1d`

But then I get this error:

```
ERROR: dav1d >= 0.5.0 not found using pkg-config
```

If I understand correctly, the problem comes from the fact that pkg-config doesn't know where to find dav1d (even if it is in ffmpeg/libdav1d, like the other ffmpeg libraries ffmpeg/libavcodec, ffmpeg/libavdevice, ffmpeg/libavformat, ...)

So I looked for a solution to tell pkg-config where libdav1d is.

`echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` returns an empty reply

so I defined the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH as it is defined in my msys 2.0 by typing: `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig:/lib/pkgconfig`

But since these folders don't exist in my msys 1.0, I created this folder (in Windows)

```
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\share\pkgconfig
```

and in this folder, I copied the file "dav1d.pc" and I modify the first line of this file (the value of variable prefix):

```
prefix=/c/projects/ffmpeg44/ffmpeg/libdav1d
libdir=${prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: libdav1d
Description: AV1 decoding library
Version: 0.9.2
Libs: -L${libdir} -ldav1d
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

But when I use ./configure, I keep having this error message: `ERROR: dav1d >= 0.5.0 not found using pkg-config`

So could someone give me step by step instructions to build (under Windows) ffmpeg with libdav1d ?

If possible, I would prefer to build libdav1d and include it in ffmpeg rather than use libdav1d already built by someone else.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is using MSVC a must? If GCC is ok, you can download a prebuilt ffmpeg (with dav1d support enabled) or use their build script.

Comment: MSVC is not really a must. I just need to be able to use the ffmpeg DLLs from an app which has to be built in Visual Studio. So your suggestion would work. But I would like to be able to build the ffmpeg DLLs by myself (as I already do without libdav1d, but now I'd like to include libdav1d in it).

Comment: If you need to use it with MSVC, then you probably must build with MSVC (like you already do). Have you looked into `vcpkg`? It seems they have `ffmpeg`, but unsure if it has dav1d support or not.

Comment: I had a look at https://vcpkg.io/en/packages.html and apparently dav1d is included. But my goal is really to be able to build ffmpeg by myself (as I already do) and include dav1d in it (that's what I am struggling with).

Comment: Vcpkg builds everything on your machine. It might be possible to extract the build scripts from it...

Comment: Make sure `MSYS2` has `pkgconfig` package installed. For this, just follow all the post-installation instructions described on their site's main page.

Answer (score 0):

I can build dav1d 0.7.0 with MinGW-w64 under MSYS using these meson flags: `-Denable_tools=true -Denable_examples=false -Dfuzzing_engine=none -Denable_tests=false -Dtestdata_tests=false`

To make `pkg-config` find the `.pc` file you should add the folder containing the `.pc` file to the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable.